# fileCache seems to expire even though I have it set to 0

Tags: filecache

I am using the fileCache command in a custom plugin. I've set it to never expire so that I can provide a special link to our client to force a refresh.

Problem is, the cache seems to be killing itself off. On one day I can see record of it regenerating three separate times, so it is

```
$craft->fileCache->add($cacheKey, $dataToAddToCache, $cacheExpire);
$craft->fileCache->add('my-hardcoded-key', 'string of data', 0);
```

So basically I am doing this.

```
if (NEED_TO_REGEN) {
   $craft->fileCache->delete($cacheKey);
}
$a_cacheVal = $craft->fileCache->get($cacheKey);
if (empty($a_cacheVal)) {
    //use the cached data
} else {
   $craft->fileCache->add($cacheKey, $dataToAddToCache, $cacheExpire);
}
```

Does admin modification of resources affect fileCache at all (updating an entry wouldn't kill of my plugin fileCache would it?) The admins is not doing a full Clear Cache inside settings or anything. So why would this particular cache be regenerating frequently (multiple times per day in some case)?

Comment: Thanks. I've changed from craft()->fileCache to craft()->cache. I can verify the date modified on the file is one year out so the "0" must be working as expected. I doubt garbage collection is the issue because the site has no where near enough traffic to have that happen as frequently as I'm seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `craft()->cache` with the [cacheMethod](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#cacheMethod) config setting set to `file` (which it is by default) instead of `craft()->fileCache`.  The latter is deprecated and won't work in Craft 3.

Yii does have [garbage collection](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.17/framework/caching/CFileCache.php#L101) on cache, and by default an item has a 0.01% change of being purged from cache regardless of expiry time.

If you think you're not being garbage collected, you can check the file modified time of the files in `craft/storage/runtime/cache`.  If you explicitly pass in `0` as an expiration time, Yii will set the file's modification date to a [year out](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.17/framework/caching/CFileCache.php#L157).